# Wanting to run power to my workshop.

Tags: wiring

I have 8/3 Romex wire and shop is 60 ft. From my house. Heard to many of different ways to do it, but I want it to be down safe and the right way. I need to know what size of subpanel and what breakers can I use? Wanting 3 outlets, 1 for lights and stereo, 1 for tools 15amp on tools nothing bigger than that and 1 for misc. Main panel in the house is 150amp cutler-hammer with 6 spaces still open.

Comment: There are LOTS of questions here about “running power to workshop”?  Did you read through any of them?  So the 60ft is an outdoor run? You can’t bury Romex, it’s also not sunlight/UV resistant.   Not sure what you had in mind, but if it’s 60feet from the house to the shop then that sounds outdoors and Romex doesn’t sound like the correct wire for the job.

Comment: Was planning on putting the Romex in 1in. Sch.40 conduit and using a 70 amp subpanel with two 30amp breakers in the main panel and one 15 amp & one 20 amp in the subpanel. Would this work or would I have any problems?

Comment: #8 NM-B (aka romex) is only good for [40 amps](http://www.cerrowire.com/ampacity-charts).  Underground is a ‘wet location’.  NM-B isn’t rated for wet locations.  That’s just the first 2 immediately obvious problems.  You should really study the other versions of your more or less “same question”.

Comment: What all do I need if I use the 6/2 Romex wire

Comment: Romex is not rated for wet locations (ie underground PVC conduit).  You need THWN.   Seriously please search the site and learn... your basic question has been asked 100’s of times.

Comment: Also NM-B (romex) is generally not used in conduit.

Comment: Also, is your panel type CH or type BR?

Comment: My main panel is type CH

Comment: Outdoor conduit is presumed to be 100% full of water.  Use wire designed to be wet, i.e. *not Romex*.  Sell it on Craigslist and buy UF-B which is made for direct burial. Remember you will be burying it with 18" of dirt above it.  If you don't want to trench 19" deep, use Rigid conduit ($$$$$) and trench 7" deep for 6" of dirt above it.